# OpenAPI schema object with changeble property passed from the path

Tags: openapi

I have OpenAPI schema object, which universally shoots back to any kind of requests to my API:

```
  schemas:
    ResponseObject:
      type: object
      properties:
        success:
          type: boolean
        data:
          oneOf:
            - type: array
              items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Category'
            - type: object
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Category'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ValidationError'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/APIToken'
        message:
          type: string
```

It looks nice that, no matter what, the user will get the response of the same structure. But from the standpoint of documentation and testing this solition smells... Because all kind of responses in my API are described as

```
  responses: 
    '201':
      description: New category has been added
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ResponseObject'
```

So it's not particularly clear what exactly is going to be in the 'data' section.
Maybe someone knows how to refactor it in a more elegant way? Some kind of passsing the argument of what is going to be in one of the properties of the response objects?

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts on this:

Basically you are deciding between a generic and a specific interface design.

The generic approach gives you consistent messages, but the interface semantics is kind of unclear (as you have already pointed out in your question). This will probably lead to more complicated logic within the components.

In a specific approach you would define different API endpoints with different request and response schemas for each of your operations. This makes the API definition longer, but the component logic should be very clear.

In my opinion, your idea of using an argument to parametrize the interface would rather combine the disadvantages of both worlds because you would need distinction of cases in both the API definition and the code.

So do you really need the generic approach? This might be that case if you need a stable interface while communication partners change over time (e.g. in a microservices scenario).
If not, I would recommend to model requests and responses with specific properties.